# How to Install mod_wsgi in a virtual Environement

Tags: apache, python-3.x, ubuntu, mod-wsgi, apxs2

## Introduction

I have a Web API writtten in python 3 and it uses flask. The code runs fine when I run the web API from the terminal and it is hosted from the following line in the code.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='', port=8010, debug='true')
```

## Current Situation

The code runs perfectly and I want to set it up on an Apache Server. However the Apache server already has websites that were built using python 2 and need mod_wsgi for python 2.

I looked up if there was a way to set up both mod-wsgi on the apache server but according to the following source you can't 
[mod_wsgi for Python 2 as well as Python 3 on one Apache server](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/21)

## Attempt at a solution

I 'm trying to install mod-wsgi into a virtual environment. I downloaded the package from here and tried to install it into the environment after activating it.

I ran  `sudo python setup.py install` from the terminal but I got the error below

> File "setup.py", line 139, in 
>       'missing Apache httpd server packages.' % APXS)
>   RuntimeError: The 'apxs' command appears not to be installed or is not executable. Please check the list of prerequisites in the documentation for this package and install any missing Apache httpd server packages.

So I opened the Read Me file that was part of zipped package and found the following

> If you wish to use a version of Apache which is installed into a non
>   standard location, you can set and export the `APXS` environment
>   variable to the location of the Apache `apxs` script for your Apache
>   installation before performing the installation.
>
> Note that nothing will be copied into your Apache installation at this
>   point. As a result, you do not need to run this as the root user
>   unless installing it into a site wide Python installation rather than
>   a Python virtual environment.
>
> To verify that the installation was successful, run the
>   `mod_wsgi-express` script with the `start-server` command::
>
> ```
> mod_wsgi-express start-server
> ```

It seems to tackle my situation since Apache is not installed in the virtual environment that I'm running the command from but I have no idea how to do it

I presume they are talking about the setup.py file and that I should change the path but I do not know how to do it syntax wise or where my APXS script is located.

Here is snippet of the code that I think needs to be modified

```
APXS = os.environ.get('APXS')

WITH_HTTPD_PACKAGE = False

if APXS is None:
    APXS = find_program(['mod_wsgi-apxs'],
            paths=[os.path.dirname(sys.executable)])
    if APXS is not None:
        WITH_HTTPD_PACKAGE = True

if APXS is None:
    APXS = find_program(['mod_wsgi-apxs', 'apxs2', 'apxs'],
            'apxs', ['/usr/sbin', os.getcwd()])
elif not os.path.isabs(APXS):
    APXS = find_program([APXS], APXS, ['/usr/sbin', os.getcwd()])

if not WITH_TARBALL_PACKAGE:
    if not os.path.isabs(APXS) or not os.access(APXS, os.X_OK):
        raise RuntimeError('The %r command appears not to be installed or '
                'is not executable. Please check the list of prerequisites '
                'in the documentation for this package and install any '
                'missing Apache httpd server packages.' % APXS)
```

## The Question

I'm doing all of this on a server running Ubuntu 12.04LTS if it helps. My question at the end are the following

1. Where is the APXS located usually in Ubuntu
2. How do I change the code snippet to make use the APXS script there

Thank you so much for Your time

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding 
turns out APXS was not installed on my APACHE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience

Turns out I forgot to install APXS on my apache server. I simply ran the code from the terminal and it worked
`sudo apt-get apache2-threaded-dev`

### Update

For Ubuntu 18 its (thank you @MagicLAMP)

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-dev
```

For Centos 7: (thank you @User)

```
yum install httpd-devel
```

Comment: On ubuntu 18 $ apt-get install apache2-dev

Answer (score 1):

For Centos 7:

```
yum install httpd-devel
```